# How to reset the timeout period of Apache IoTDB to longer time?

Tags: timeout, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Can the timeout period of Apache IoTDB be reset? I wonder if it can ibe set longer, for example, set to1 hour? I am trying to use IoTDB after updating to Version 1.0.1, and there is no such problem with the older version, V 0.13.3. Does anyone know which parameter I should change?

I am trying to use IoTDB after updating to Version 1.0.1, and there is no such problem with the older version, V 0.13.3. Does anyone know which parameter I should change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to adjust “query_timeout_threshold” parameter in Cli tool of Apache IoTDB. For example, if you want the timeout period to be one hour, you can set query_timeout_threshold=360000.